# How to run Selenium tests in Grid in one browser window?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

When using only Selenium server it was possible to run the tests in the single browser window with the setting

```
-java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar -singleWindow
```

When switched to grid 2, -singleWindow parameter is not working anymore.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing the singleWindow parameter to RC node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it happen by running the following line:

```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.2.0.jar -role webdriver -singleWindow -hub http://192.168.1.149:4444/grid/register -port 5557
```

Seems like the order of the parameters is important.